# pass actionlink generated url to javascript method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to pass the url generated via Html.ActionLink to a javascript function argument. So, how could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Url.Action` helper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("Foo", "Bar")';
    someJavascriptfunction(url);
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could extract this information directly from the DOM. Let's suppose that you have an anchor in your DOM:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "Foo", "Bar")
```

that you want to AJAXify in your javascript file:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            // Do something with the result of the AJAX call
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```